# GTA V Textures loading slowly

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

So I've got Gta V and while playing textures are blury or they don't even load (usually when I'm going fast) the other problem is that my game freezes or it just randomly drop fps

Comment: I'm assuming this is on PC, correct? Does your machine meet the minimum required specs?

Comment: It should : Gtx 950 2gb oc edition , i5 4590 8gb ram I usually have above 60fps only problems are above

Comment: Can you try the solution proposed [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/611703709831723514/?ctp=2#c613956964589321628) and see if that helps with the texture issue?

Comment: Also, I'm seeing a lot of people in forum threads saying that uninstall and reinstalling their display drivers helped with stuttering/framerate drops. Maybe try that as well?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the amount of GDDR5 RAM in your gpu most of the time.
I had the same problem in mirrors edge: Catalyst and Fallout4. but is fixed now that i have a gtx 1060.

would you mind telling us your system specs since that makes it easier to pinpoint the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going really fast in a vehicle; textures tend to load very slowly if you are running an old SSD. RAM can also come into play, but 8GB is fine for GTA 5.

Comment: I'm not fully sure how this does answer the question. Could u clarify a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your graphics driver and reinstall it and it should fix your issues. From what im hearing, it sounds like a graphics driver problem. Someone went wrong with the download, so id reinstall it again. Also, make sure you update your graphics driver, every time a new version comes out, that will help with games over all. Server could be issue also, it happens on consoles too, and it recently stopped. So either reinstall or wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: I feel like this has a chance to work, but feel like it won't work even more.

Comment: lol what if it even get's messed up more

Comment: Thats unlikely to happen.

Comment: Why will this work?  Good answers provide explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try lowering your graphics, to reduce FPS drop. Some graphics settings are really intensive, so this might be a problem too. If you would like to change your graphics settings, press Escape (Or start on a controller) and Go to settings: Goto graphics, and then look at the video memory, Experiment with getting it as low as possible, while still pretty high, so the graphics aren't basically Roblox or Unturned :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing that helped me when I had this issue was updating my Nvidia drivers. Sometimes I even had to downgrade the drivers because the new ones weren't optimized, but now the new ones are perfect. Also, if you are using the self radio feature, I'd recommend disabling it as this can cause slow loading of textures as well.